# Generating short strings (letters and numbers) with lowest length possible (for url shortner): Try random or Use pre-generated data set?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, algorithm, performance

I am developing a url shortner and I would like to know your opinion on this matter.

I want to generate shortlinks, for the shortlinks I need shortstrings.
For the shortstrings I want only letters and numbers, and starting with the length of 3 I want the users to get the smallest possible string as long as it is available.

If I allow only letters and numbers, for strings with the length of 3, we can have 46656 possibilities.

I've though about 2 paths:

1. Generating random string --> Checking for availability (does not exist in shortlinks table - meaning not yet used) --> If not yet in use we use it --> If already in use, the system needs to generate another random string and check again for availability, and repeat until we find one that is available. Considering that we have 46656 possibilities for the length of 3, eventually, as the shortstrings/links are taken, the system would have to retry the random and recheck for availability more times ( meaning more queries, meaning waiting depending on the amount of conflicts ), also I would need to know when to start generating strings with the length of 4 ( when all the 46656 possibilities are taken ). Considering my table can have an 'unique' flag for the shortstrings/links, I would only have to check if totals are >= 46656, to start generating strings with the length of 4, and then after that >= (46656 + the total possibilities with the length of 4), to start generating strings with the length of 5.. and so on.. ( some math )..
2. Seeding the database on project install / post project install as needed: I can have a 'shortstrings' table, with 'shortstring' and 'is_available' for example, and have a seeder seed this data (aaa, aab, aac...) with the is_available=1, I can initially decide to seed all the possibilities with the length of 3, or also 4, etc. (So either having alot of available links right from the start, or as needed: seed more). This way when generating a shortlink, I would just have to find() the next is_available=1 shortstring, and when used set it's is_available to 0 ( no retries, not generating randoms and possibly having conflicts ). If I don't want to manually monitor / seed the available links, I can have the system check for how many available links are left and if the number is low tell it to seed for the next length ( and this would make alot more links available , since all possibilities with the length of 4 are way more than with the lenght of 3)

I believe the second option is more performant, and it is what I am going for ( I have already set it up ) but I would like to know more opinions on this matter.

Just in case you want to know, I am using php/laravel/mariadb/mysql for this case scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"we can have 46656 possibilities"_ - but you should probably not _use_ all of those to begin with; usually you don't want people to be able to simply "increase" an existing shortlink identifier, and get a different _working_ one that way ...

Comment: I could still fetch a random record from the database, and the is_available flag would still work, but let's say having sequential links is not a problem, (aaa, aab for the next one, and then aac), which would perform better?

Comment: If you just want to create the codes in sequential order (first one gets `aaa`, second one then gets `aab` - and _not_ a randomly determined, still "free" `xyz` instead) - then I would not bother with putting those actual codes into the database to begin with. Instead, I'd use a standard auto-increment integer ID - and apply some logic that "translates" between your alphanumeric codes, and integers. (Depending on whether "letters" means lowercase only, or lower- and uppercase, that would basically be a conversion between base10 and base36 or base62 then.)

Comment: considering the first part: the closer you get to your max amount, the longer it will takes using a brute force random approach. You will probably never be able to fill all of them (in a finite time).

If sequential links are not a problem, just start by 000 or aaa and increase them by a defined order.

Comment: Ok so I understand now that I could create some kind of formula to transform a number into the next sequential possibility ( 0 some how to be translated into aaa, 1 into aab , 2 into aac.. etc until aaz.. aa1..aa2.. ) and that formula would never give me a repeated one based on an incremental number and I would not have to seed the database and would not run into conflicts and have to repeat queries.

Comment: But let's say now, that I don't want sequential strings, using the second path I explained in the question, I could still use order by Random, when fetching from the database, using is_available=1 flag - but this still would need pre-generated dataset as explained..So then how would I generate a random string, with the lowest possible length (starting with 3), using letters and numbers, without risking running into conflicts / repeating fetch query many times to check for availability (as the shortstrings/links availability decrease for the length of 3 ( or 4 , or 5.. )?)

Comment: After you generate a "sequential" string, you "whiten" it -- modify each character by adding to it (modulo the number of characters) a hash of all the other characters.  This operation is reversible, so it never generates duplicates, and it makes random-looking strings.

Comment: @MattTimmermans but the whole point is to make it a short string, the shortest possible string , starting with 3 of LENGTH, and only going to 4 of length after all possibilities with 3 of LENGTH are used up. Adding a hash to it would miss the point.

Comment: You don't *add hashes*, you modify each character according to the hash of the other characters.  Modifying each character according to the hash of the other characters doesn't change the length.

Comment: I'm having really hard time understanding @MattTimmermans, lets say my Url Shortner has not yet generated any links, the first short string generated will be AAA ( according to alphabet and minimum string length defined in the question), how do I generate the first string? and how do I generate the next with your theory/formula/knowledge/hashing way ? ( that will allow me to always get the next, and increase indefinitely , AAA is first, then after 999 we get AAAA, and then after 9999 we get AAAAA... Thanks for your time!

Comment: Since you're trying, I'll write you an answer

Answer (score 0):

In general terms, you have two workflows. The one in which you receive an url, generate a short identifier, store it and present it to the user. The other one, when you translate your identifers back to their original URL. There's not much else to a generic link shortener, so your problem boils down to figuring out the alphanumeric identifier keeping it short, and ensuring its uniqueness. It's all a tradeoff between efficiency and shortness, the latter being the most valuable, in your eyes.

I'd say the bottleneck in this case is the roundtrip to the database, so the less queries you perform, the better.

---

Your first approach is to retrieve every used identifier, then generate random strings until you come up with one that's available, at which point you perform the insertion. As you approach depletion and you find yourself performing tens of thousands of iterations (incurring in a potentially serious race condition) you plan to bump the identifier length to 4 and so on, This means you need to perform 3 queries for each incoming link:

- retrieving the used identifers
- retrieving the current length
- performing the actual insertion

Perhaps you wouldn't really store the current length in the DDBB, you could use an environment variable and read it statically from the config, but this still needs for human supervision to decide the right time to bump the length.

---

Your second approach would be to generate sequential identifers. This sounds more efficient, indeed, but leaves you open for enumeration from malicious users. This might seem irrelevant for your use case, but you shouldn't make assumptions in that regard from your end user's point of view. If you go for that approach, you still need to perform two queries

- retrieving the last used identifier
- storing the current link

---

I would humbly encourage you to take a look at at [Hashids](https://hashids.org/). It's a deterministic, reversible algorithm to encode numbers to alphanumeric strings. There are implementations for PHP, Ruby, Java, Python, Javascript and most well known languages (including PostgreSQL and PLpgSQL).

Starting from a salt that you hard code in your environment (for example) the hashes are unique to your app, meaning a third party wouldn't be able to compute the original ID without knowing it. The identifers are url friendly and curse words are avoided by design.

**However**, the shortest identifier would be of length 8. If you're willing to compromise on the length, rest assured that 8 characters are enough to encode roughly 300 billions of links. **This approach needs for just one query**: the actual insertion, after which you grab the ID and encode it to the final hash.

There are other approaches, of course, Encoding the PK to base64 is much cheaper, but the outcome's length is unactractive (you need 16 characters to encode 300 billions of links), plus it's still open to enumeration. UUIDs are extremely secure and unique, but their length is even more unnactractive.

Answer (score 0):

1. create a table with id --> URL; the `id` will be `AUTO_INCREMENT`, so it will start with 1 and continue 'forever'.  (See below)
2. When inserting a new URL, get the id
3. Convert the id to hex (4 bits per byte) or base64 (6 bits per byte).  The first 4095 URLs could be encoded in 3 hex characters or 2 base64 characters.  The first 16 million: 6 hex or 4 base64.

Note:  Hackers will quickly discover the pattern and can pull up all your URLs.  If you need the 'short' URLs to be more cryptic, you will have to sacrifice "short" some.

```
CREATE TABLE Urls (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    url VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    UNIQUE(url)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO Urls (url)
    VALUES (?)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

(Caution: I may not have the syntax exactly correct.)

The IODKU (upsert) will either add a new row or discover the existing id if the URL already exists.  The LAST_INSERT_ID is a kludge buried deep in the ref manual.

Answer (score -1):

To write an url shortener, you just need a counter to make sure that each string you generate is unique, and a table that remembers which URL each generated string maps to.

To shorten an URL:

1. remember the counter value (call it n), and increment the counter
2. convert the counter value into a string such that each unique number produces a unique string; and
3. map the string to the URL in the database.

The cleverness goes into step 2. You have stated two criteria:  You want the string to be short, starting at 3 chars, and you want it to "look random".

Here's how you can convert a number to a string like that in python (sorry, no perl for me.  I'm sure you can figure it out):

```py
# These are the characters we will use in generated strings
charset="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"

def numberToString(n):
    base = len(charset)

    # convert the number to base len(charset)
    chars=[]
    while n > 0:
        chars.append(n%base)
        n = n//base
    while len(chars) < 3:
        chars.append(0)

    # whiten (make random-looking) by modifying each
    # character with a hash of the others
    hash = 23634562
    for i in range(0,len(chars)):
        # the char is reversibly affected by previous characters
        chars[i] = (chars[i] + hash + (hash//256)) % base
        hash = ((hash + chars[i])*31) % 1000000007

    # do it again in the other direction
    chars.reverse()
    hash = 23634562
    for i in range(0,len(chars)):
        # the char is reversibly affected by previous characters
        chars[i] = (chars[i] + hash + (hash//256)) % base
        hash = ((hash + chars[i])*31) % 1000000007
    
    # make the string
    return str.join("", [charset[c] for c in chars])
```

Try it online: https://ideone.com/NEvzs0